# i already created resources manually, now i want to change the configuration of resource with terraform

Tags: git, github, terraform, devops, terraform-provider-github

I have already created github repository manually earlier, now i want to enable branch auto deletion with terraform although i have tested that feature manually.
can someone please help me in this.

can someone give me solution for this

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are just trying to have Terraform manage a manually created resource, correct?

If so, it should be pretty straight forward. You need to add the resource to your config and provide the arguments that match it's current config. Then you need to import the resource.

You can use the docs to reference any arguments you might need for your specific usage. https://registry.terraform.io/providers/integrations/github/latest/docs/resources/repository